# Regexp replace everything between parenthes

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, parentheses

I would like to know if anyone can help me figuring out a regex that replaces everything within parentheses.

My examples are:

```
grouping(elllo)

grouping(function() {
   console.log("hello")
})
```

So, I would like to replace everything inside `()` matching the `grouping`.

I only went to this stage:

```
\bgrouping(\(([^)]+)\))
```

However, it doesn't match all the newlines and stops on the first `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match balanced parentheses in Ruby with conditionals:

```
\bgrouping(\((?>[^()]|(\g<1>))*+\))
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/y2hgrkLKv5)

Here is how you can do it in Ruby:

```
rx = /\bgrouping(\((?>[^()]|(\g<1>))*+\))/
txt = "grouping(elllo)\n\ngrouping(function() {\n   console.log(\"hello\")\n})"
puts txt.gsub(rx) { |m| m.gsub($~[1], '(NEWTEXT)') }
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Kil2aZ)

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
\b(grouping\()(?:\([^()]*\)|[^()])*\)
```

Replacement string:

```
\1foo)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qM6hP2/1)